# PrepareForSegue Not Passing All of the Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am using a modal segue to pass data from SignUpViewController to RAVerificationViewController. For some reason, my name, password, phone, and email values are nil but dorm and role choices show up (they are values selected from a picker). I see that they're being passed correctly from the first view controller but they don't show up in the next one. Help!

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"signUpToRAVerification"]) {
        RAVerificationViewController *ravc = (RAVerificationViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSInteger roleRow = [_rolePickerChoice selectedRowInComponent:0];
        NSString *role = [self pickerView: _rolePickerChoice titleForRow:roleRow forComponent:1];
        ravc.role = role;
        NSString *email = _emailOneField.text;
        ravc.name = _nameField.text;
        ravc.password = _passwordTwoField.text;
        ravc.email = email;
        ravc.phoneNumber = _phoneNumberField.text;
        NSInteger dormRow = [_dormPickerChoice selectedRowInComponent:0];
        NSString *dorm = [self pickerView: _dormPickerChoice titleForRow:dormRow forComponent:1];
        ravc.dormChoice= dorm;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing with the data in the other VC:

```
if([_raCodeField.text isEqualToString:code]) {
        NSLog(@"The email is: %@", email);
        //RA good to go, let's save him/her in our DB!
        PFUser* user = [PFUser user];
        user[@"role"] = _role;
        user[@"Name"] = name;
        user.password = password;
        user.email = email;
        user.username = email;
        user[@"phone_number"] = phoneNumber;
        user[@"dorm"] = _dormChoice;
        [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
```

For the entire SignUpViewController: https://gist.github.com/vinamratasingal/542dc10bf1674173d2de

For the entire raVerificationViewController: https://gist.github.com/vinamratasingal/758d3a11a3ddf6d7e3a3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing us your header file for your `RAVerificationViewController`, but I can almost guarantee that the problem is that your properties are using the `weak` property attribute. You need to make sure they are using the `strong` property attribute.

Otherwise, the data will not have any strong references and it will be deallocated from memory.

Comment: The missing underscore is because of the "@synthesize" at the top of the class... it doesn't fix anything (I had it for underscores and then added @synthesize for each broken property and that didn't fix anything)

Comment: You don't need to use @synthesize anymore in most cases. That's automatically taken care of for you. Post more code from both of your view controllers so we can see how you have everything setup.

Comment: please see the attached file links above to the entire files. I wasn't sure what code was relevant so I posted links to both VC's. Here they are again: For the entire SignUpViewController: https://gist.github.com/vinamratasingal/542dc10bf1674173d2de

For the entire raVerificationViewController: https://gist.github.com/vinamratasingal/758d3a11a3ddf6d7e3a3

I also set breakpoints and saw that the class variables for those four variables (name, email, etc.) are nil, but dorm and role choice are set properly.

Comment: @VinamrataSingal what happens if you log the string

Comment: Fixed it. My properties for the variables in the raAuthenticationViewController class were given the "weak" attribute instead of "nonatomic"

Comment: @VinamrataSingal, well, then user3344977 was right, so you can accept his answer.